# Secondary partition became primary

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning

I was using Windows 10 some time ago and decided to go back to 8.1 by wiping out my main partition and installing 8.1 over it. Since I wanted to backup a lot of stuff, I made a secondary NTFS partition to store some files in it, before I wiped my main partition. But, after I installed 8.1 on my main partition, the backup partition I made became a primary partition, with the System status. Now I can't delete it and merge with my main partition.

I tried using third party tools like EaseUS, also Diskpart, but nothing. Even though `delete partition override` didn't throw me an error, I still couldn't delete it. It's a 60GB partition.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System` in `Healthy(...)` of `G:` probably indicated that it is the "active" partition (i.e. the `bootmgr` on it is used), which is why you cannot delete it.

To confirm that, you can check with `detail partition` in `diskpart` or `bcdedit`.

For example,

```
diskpart
select disk 0
select partition 2
detail partition
```

It should tell you `Active: Yes`.

`bcdedit` should show that `device` is `partition=G:` under the `Windows Boot Manager` section.

To fix that, you can use `active` in `diskpart` to mark the `C:` as the active one instead.

For example,

```
diskpart
select disk 0
select partition 1
active
```

You better make sure `C:` has a set of bootloader (`bootmgr`, BCD Store...) before you reboot though:

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f BIOS
```

(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824874.aspx)

Once you rebooted, you should see that `System` in `Healthy(...)` of `G:` moved to that of `C:`, and you should be able to delete `G:` then.

P.S. The `Boot` shown in `Healthy(...)` in Disk Management merely means `bootmgr` booted the `\Windows` on that partition. It has nothing to do with the "active" partition mentioned above.

Comment: For some reason after I got back home from university, it threw me a boot error saying that I should use a proper boot device. Probably some boot config that got messed up, which I don't know how it did, since I wasn't able to mess around with my partitions. I had no knowledge on how to repair it and was with a Windows 10 installation disk in hand so I just installed it over. I remember unassigning my partition's letter, so it was still allocated, it might've been that. Either way, I was able to delete that volume and expand my C: partition once I installed Windows 10. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, by "secondary partition" you actually mean a *logical partition.* The term "secondary partition" doesn't clearly identify anything in particular.

It's also unclear why a change from logical to primary form would prevent you from deleting or otherwise manipulating the partition. It could be that something else is causing that particular problem. For instance, some tools won't modify a partition that's currently in use. Much more detail on the current state of your partition table, what you want to do, and what tools you're using may be required if you're to get much help.

That said, it is possible to convert from primary to logical or vice-versa, albeit with some significant caveats. My own [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) program can do this, for instance. I've heard that some more mainstream third-party Windows tools can do the same, although I'm not familiar with the details. As it's not clear to me that the partition's status as a primary partition is the source of your problem, I do *not* advise you to rush out and make this change, though -- at least, not unless and until you determine that you really do need to change the partition type.

Comment: Or he actually meant a "second" partition...